# Search for multiple

Tags: django

**My search function receives a search term in any of the following ways:**

- first_name  "thomas"
- last_name "smith"
- first_name last_name "thomas smith"

I'm trying to build a queryset that will find the client "thomas" by any of those terms, but will narrow the results to only "thomas smith" instead of "thomas jones" or "george smith" if both names are supplied.

I've done a lot of research on how to use filters, Q objects, string splitting, and for loops to accomplish this, but so far no luck.

```
MODEL:
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

VIEW:
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('s', '').strip()
    if query:
        client_set = (
            (Q(first_name__in=query) & Q(last_name__in=query)) |
            Q(first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=query)  
        )
    else:
        client_list = []
    return render_to_response("search.html", {
        "client_list": client_list,
        "query": query
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The above code works when searching "thom" but finds nothing for "thomas smith".  How can I rewrite this to function as described?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using `first_name__in` instead of `first_name__icontains`? Cause I'm pretty sure that `__in` doesn't work the way you expect it to work ;)

Comment: I've tried it with __icontains also.  My understanding of __in is that it should translated in to LIKE at the SQL level.  While my SQL is rusty, I'm hoping that means it will take any part of the search query and match it to the field value so that "thomas smith" will match "thomas" in the first name, and then "smith" in the last_name.  If it did work that way, I think my query would work.  Evidently it doesn't.  :-)

Comment: The `__contains` operator will be converted to `LIKE` and `__icontains` will be converted to `ILIKE`. The `__in` is usually used for a primary key lookup and will be converted to something like `id IN (...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this should do what you want:

```
def search(request):
    name = request.GET.get('s', '').strip().split(' ', 1)
    client_set = Client.objects.all()

    if len(name) == 2:
        first_name, last_name = name
        client_set = client_set.filter(
            first_name__icontains=first_name,
            last_name__icontains=last_name,
        )
    else:
        name = name[0]
        client_set = client_set.filter(
            client_set.filter(first_name__icontains=name)
            | client_set.filter(last_name__icontains=name)
        )

    return render_to_response("search.html", {
        "client_list": client_list,
        "query": query
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Shouldn't client_set in 'if else' condition be client_list?

Comment: Thank you for this code.  It looks like it will do exactly what I need.  I hadn't thought of just searching for a condition where there were exactly 2 names, and handling that way.  I'll come back and comment again after I have time to work on this project and implement this.  Thank you again !

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am using Q objects for this, but your idea to treat exactly 2 strings separately was very helpful.  I was trying to be more complicated and allow for x strings.  But that wasn't necessary.